# Finding list of edges in graphviz in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, graphviz

Is there any way to get list of edges in graphviz in python. In my program I wanted to check whether edge already exist between nodes before adding edge in the **directed graph**. I couldn't find any function like `get_edge()` or `has_connected()` function in grahviz in python. Is there any other way of doing the above mentioned task? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

if your goal is to avoid duplicates edges, use `Digraph(strict=True)` or `Graph(strict=True)`

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem. I don't see anything in the source code that would indicate a convenient way of checking if an edge is in a graph.

If you're dealing with a very simple graph then maybe this will help.

```
def has_edge(graph, v1, v2):
    tail_name = graph._quote_edge(v1)
    head_name = graph._quote_edge(v2)
    return (graph._edge % (tail_name, head_name, '')) in graph.body
```

I adapted this from the 'edge()' method in graphviz/dot.py. It doesn't handle any attributes.

From what I can see, the `graph.body` is a list of strings representing nodes and edges.

Answer (score 0):

Here's `get_edges` to get a list of edges for a given graphviz digraph (or graph).
The graph can be expressed as a `BaseGraph` or `Source` object, or simply the source string. But default it will return pairs of node ids (strings), but you can tell `get_edges` to give you anything (including the `pydot.Edge` object itself, containing all its properties.

```py
from typing import Tuple, List, Iterable
from pydot import Dot, graph_from_dot_data, Edge
from graphviz.graphs import BaseGraph
from graphviz import Source


def edge_to_node_ids(edge: Edge) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Returns the node id pair for the edge object"""
    return (edge.get_source(), edge.get_destination())


def get_graph_dot_obj(graph_spec) -> List[Dot]:
    """Get a dot (graphs) object list from a variety of possible sources (postelizing inputs here)"""
    _original_graph_spec = graph_spec
    if isinstance(graph_spec, (BaseGraph, Source)):
        # get the source (str) from a graph object
        graph_spec = graph_spec.source
    if isinstance(graph_spec, str):
        # get a dot-graph from dot string data
        graph_spec = graph_from_dot_data(graph_spec)
    # make sure we have a list of Dot objects now
    assert isinstance(graph_spec, list) and all(
        isinstance(x, Dot) for x in graph_spec
    ), (
        f"Couldn't get a proper dot object list from: {_original_graph_spec}. "
        f"At this point, we should have a list of Dot objects, but was: {graph_spec}"
    )
    return graph_spec


def get_edges(graph_spec, postprocess_edges=edge_to_node_ids):
    """Get a list of edges for a given graph (or list of lists thereof).
    If ``postprocess_edges`` is ``None`` the function will return ``pydot.Edge`` objects from
    which you can extract any information you want.
    By default though, it is set to extract the node pairs for the edges, and you can
    replace with any function that takes ``pydot.Edge`` as an input.
    """
    graphs = get_graph_dot_obj(graph_spec)
    n_graphs = len(graphs)

    if n_graphs > 1:
        return [get_edges(graph, postprocess_edges) for graph in graphs]
    elif n_graphs == 0:
        raise ValueError(f"Your input had no graphs")
    else:
        graph = graphs[0]
        edges = graph.get_edges()
        if callable(postprocess_edges):
            edges = list(map(postprocess_edges, edges))
        return edges
```

Test:

```py
digraph_dot_source = """
DIGRAPH{
    rain -> traffic
    rain -> wet
    traffic, wet -> moody
}
"""

assert (
    get_edges(digraph_dot_source)
    == get_edges(Source(digraph_dot_source))
    == [('rain', 'traffic'), ('rain', 'wet'), ('wet', 'moody')]
)

graph_dot_source = """
GRAPH{
    rain -- traffic
    rain -- wet
    traffic, wet -- moody
}
"""

assert (
    get_edges(graph_dot_source)
    == get_edges(Source(graph_dot_source))
    == [('rain', 'traffic'), ('rain', 'wet'), ('wet', 'moody')]
)
```